# How to specify a dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to create a family tree of some sort. I have a drop down box that's it options are being dynamically added when I make a new family and prompts the user to add a child of the selected family.

I'm trying to append the child after the table of the selected family but I have no idea what kind of ID are being generated when they're dynamically made

code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
//To Create Familes 
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
        var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table');
    var family = document.getElementById('famname').value;

    $('#family input[type = text],input[type = text],input[type =    text],input[type = text]').each( function() {
    str =  '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
    $(this).val('');
    table.append( str );
    }); 
    $('#container').append(table);
    $('#select').append($('<option />', { text: family } ) );
});

//To Create child to right family 
$('#submit2').on('click', function() {

var child = prompt("Enter the name of the child you wanna put to the selected family ");
something.after(child);
});
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id ="family" method = "post" target="_parent">
   Enter Family Name <input type = "text" name = "famname" id = "famname" > <br>
   Enter Address <input type = "text" name = "address"> <br>
   Enter Father's name <input type = "text" name = "dad"> <br>
   Enter Mother's name<input type = "text" name = "mom"> <br>
   <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<p>Select Which family you want to add a child to</p>
<form id = "child">
   <select id ="select"></select>
   <input id="submit2" type="button" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<div id  = "container">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

any idea's of how to append after the selected families? or is there a better of doing this

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to actually add elements rather than HTML for example:

```
var test = document.createElement('table');
test.setAttribute('id', 'test_id');
document.body.appendChild(test);
console.log(document.getElementById('test_id'));
```

to reference it, be sure to add an id and/or a class using the setAttribute javascript call or the .attr() or .prop() methods in jquery.

Comment: you mean this is best way to add the children? or adding both the child and families? if so does this mean I for 'test id' I have to make one for every family/child made?

Comment: That was just an example of how to create an element.  I'm a little confused by what you're trying to add, but you specify what kind of element you want to create with createElement, and you'd put something unique about the element instead of test_id, like the family name or the child's name or a combination of both, or an incrementing number.  When an element is added and there isn't an Id specified there won't be one.  you have to give it one whether it's dynamically created or not.

Answer (score 0):

That's not very clear as to exactly what you're trying to do, but here's a tidier version that adds the child as a new row after the family's row:

```all
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var cur_id = 0;

        //To Create Familes 
        $('#submit').on("click", function(ev) {
          var id = "family" + cur_id++,
            $row = $('<tr id="' + id + '"></tr>');

          $('#select').append('<option value="' + id + '">' + $("#famname").val() + '</option>');

          $('#family :text')
            .each(function() {
              $row.append('<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>');
            })
            .val("");

          $('#container table').append($row);
        });

        //To Create child to right family 
        $('#submit2').click(function(ev) {
          var child = prompt("Enter the name of the child you wanna put to the selected family "),
              id = $("#select").val();

          $("#" + id)
            .after("<tr><td>" + child +  "</td></tr>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id ="family" method = "post" target="_parent">
      <label>Enter Family Name <input type="text" name="famname" id="famname"></label><br>
      <label>Enter Address <input type="text" name="address"></label><br>
      <label>Enter Father's name <input type = "text" name="dad"></label><br>
      <label>Enter Mother's name <input type="text" name="mom"></label><br>
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <p>Select Which family you want to add a child to</p>
    <form id="child">
      <select id="select"></select>
      <input id="submit2" type="button" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <div id="container">
      <table class="table"></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

//To Create Familes 
$('#submit').on('click',function(){

    var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table');
    var family = document.getElementById('famname').value;

    $('#family input[type = text],input[type = text],input[type =    text],input[type = text]').each(function() {

        str =  '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';

        $(this).val('');

        table.append(str);
        table.addClass(family);


    });





    $('#container').append(table);

    $('#select').append($('<option />', {text: family, value:family}));



});

//To Create child to right family 
var fam, child, str;

$(document).on('change', '#select', function(){

    $('#submit2').show();
    $('#child_name').show();

    fam = $(this).children('#select :selected').val();

});


$(document).on('click', '#submit2', function(){
    child = $('#child_name').val();

    $('#submit2').hide();
    $('#child_name').hide();

    str =  '<td>' + child + '</td>'
    $('.'+fam).append(str);
});



});

</script>

</head>

<body>



<form id ="family" method = "post" target="_parent">
Enter Family Name <input type = "text" name = "famname" id = "famname" > <br>
Enter Address <input type = "text" name = "address"> <br>
 Enter Father's name <input type = "text" name = "dad"> <br>
Enter Mother's name<input type = "text" name = "mom"> <br>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<p>Select Which family you want to add a child to</p>

<select id ="select">
</select>
<input type="text" id="child_name" style="display:none;">
<input id="submit2" type="submit" value="button" name="submit" style="display:none;">


<div id  = "container">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**this should do, I tested this already...hope this helps**